# Can't calculate isoline for bicycle transport mode

Tags: here-api

I am currently evaluating HERE and trying to calculate an isoline for a bicycle, but keep receiving an error response, as follows:

```
{
  "_type": "ns2:RoutingServiceErrorType",
  "type": "ApplicationError",
  "subtype": "InvalidInputData",
  "details": "Isoline for 'bicycle' Transport Mode is not supported",
  "additionalData": [
    {
      "key": "mode",
      "value": "fastest;bicycle;traffic:disabled"
    }
  ],
  "metaInfo": {
    "timestamp": "2016-07-25T13:58:35Z",
    "mapVersion": "8.30.62.159",
    "moduleVersion": "7.2.71.0-39010",
    "interfaceVersion": "2.6.25"
  }
}
```

Request details:

```
https://isoline.route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json?app_id=<my_app_id>&app_code=<my_app_code>&mode=fastest;bicycle;traffic:disabled&rangetype=time&start=geo!51.509373,-0.122572&range=5503
```

If I change the transport mode from bicycle to pedestrian, I get a successful response, so assume the request is OK apart from that bit. Maybe the Evaluation plan has a limitation on isolines for bicycles? Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In documentation, https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-isoline.html mentioned that for isoline routing only car, truck and pedestrian modes are supported at the moment.